# Is it possible to substract 2 hours from the TODAY() function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if it is possible to substract 2 hours from the TODAY() function so that when I use it in cell A1 let's say, if it's 01:30 AM Time 22 September it considers being 21 September (11:30 PM Time)? I don;t need time, I need only the date to change accordingly but with a delay of 2 hours so to speak.

Comment: If you want to subtract two hours, then you need the time. There's no way to avoid that if you want to use hours or minutes or seconds. Two hours from 11:00 PM on 21 September is still 21 September. If you're using it at 01:30AM, then you have a time, and you can subtract two hours from that time to move back to the day before.

Comment: In my sheet, I have a table containing several columns. In the first column of the table (B) I have dates corresponding to each day for the next year. I use conditional formatting to highlight each row corresponding to current day. The formula I use is =INDIRECT("B" &Row())=TODAY() which works fine but I need it to consider today as being until 2:00 AM next day. I just tried using INDIRECT("B"&ROW())=NOW()-Time(26,0,0) but that does not seem to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is in my answer below, but if you are trying to compare to today() - 2 hours as a date it would be `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())=DATEVALUE(NOW()-(1/24*2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=NOW()-(1/24*2)`

Subtracting a full integer is removing a day, you have to divide 1/24 to get hours then multiply by the number of hours you want, hence 1/24*2

To return just the date:

`=INT(NOW()-(1/24*2))`

Comment: I'm using the formula I posted above to format(highlight) cells. It doesn't have to display anything. I tried substrating 2/24 from now and today and that also does not work.

Comment: @BogdanTrif `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())=DATEVALUE(NOW()-(1/24*2))` did not work? Make sure it's wrapped in `DATEVALUE()`

Comment: No, just tried it. If I replace TODAY() in my initial formula with DateValue(.....) no row gets highlighted, nothing happens

Comment: hmm...it works fine in my testing, maybe there is something else happening with data types, are you sure that the value in `"B"&ROW()` is a date and not datetime?

Comment: Maybe try `=DATEVALUE(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))=DATEVALUE(NOW()-(1/24*2))` to ensure that both are actually dates.

Comment: I tested inserting this formula (=DateValue(now()-(1/24*2)) in a separate cell and the result is #value!

Comment: I tested datevalue before Indirect and I also made sure that all the cells in column b are dates but it still does not work

Comment: Ah, I was testing in g sheets because I thought these basic formulas worked the same. in excel though, i had to change it to `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())=ROUNDDOWN(NOW()-(1/24*2),0)` sorry about that

Comment: Actually, `INT(NOW()-(1/24*2))` works too and is a little shorter. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: It worked perfectly with RoundDown - thank you so much, I appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry about the confusion. If my answer resolved your question please mark it as the correct answer for this thread.

Comment: @ValonMiller you should update your answer with the corrected version shown in your comment...